# Type or Namespace name not found in Azure Functions c# (Botframework)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, botframework

I have a bot using Bot Framework and C# language and I want to connect it to the azure functions following the  [manage Long-running operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-long-operations-guidance?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) documentation from Microsoft but I'm getting an error whenever I try to run and test the run.csx file on the portal and the error says that the name space name was not found on multiple of libraires.

the code below is the run.csx file

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine;
using System.Threading;

public static async Task Run(string queueItem, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processing");

    JsonSerializerSettings jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { 
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
    var originalActivity =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Activity>(queueItem, j 
    sonSettings);
    // Perform long operation here....
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));

   if(originalActivity.Value.ToString().Equals("option 1", 
     StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   {
     originalActivity.Value = " (Result for long operation one!)";
   }
   else if(originalActivity.Value.ToString().Equals("option 2", 
   StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
   {
      originalActivity.Value = " (A different result for operation two!)";
   }

   originalActivity.Value = "LongOperationComplete:" + originalActivity.Value;
   var responseActivity =  new Activity("event");
   responseActivity.Value = originalActivity;
   responseActivity.Name = "LongOperationResponse";
   responseActivity.From = new ChannelAccount("GenerateReport", "AzureFunction");

   var directLineSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DirectLineSecret");
   using(DirectLineClient client = new DirectLineClient(directLineSecret))
   {
      var conversation = await client.Conversations.StartConversationAsync();
      await client.Conversations.PostActivityAsync(conversation.ConversationId, 
   responseActivity);
   }

   log.LogInformation($"Done...");
   }
```

the image below is the error message
[image: image of error message]

Comment: I am no expert on the Bot Framework or this way of making Azure Functions, but I presume you also need to reference the Bot Framework Nuget package? So perhaps `#r Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core` at the top? And perhaps others?

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Functions environment only imports a base set of assemblies by default, and the `Microsoft.Bot` libraries are not among them. You will need to reference those assemblies before you can import the namespace. This means you will need both a `#r` reference and the `using` import. See the Azure Functions document on [referencing external assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp?tabs=functionsv2#referencing-external-assemblies) for a list of what is provided by default and an example of how to reference.